# How do I make a partial update on a ManyToManyField? I also need it validated. Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to partially-update instances through GET requests.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^classes/(?P<pk>\d+)/add_student/(?P<student_id>\d+)', views.add_student),
]
```

models.py

```
class Class(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField('Student', related_name='classes')
    max_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...

class Student(models.Model):
    ...
```

The following does not work, but what I want is to be able to partially-update a class_ instance. I want to add a student to this Class instance. 
Also, I want the validate code in my serializer to reject the update if it is not good.

views.py

```
def add_student(request, pk, student_id):
    class_ = get_object_or_404(Class, id=pk)
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=student_id)
    class_.students.add(student)
    serializer = ClassSerializer(
        class_, 
        data={'students': class_.students}, 
        partial=True
            )
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save()
    return redirect('class-detail', pk=pk)
```

serializer.py

```
class ClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def validate(self, data):
        students = data['students']
        max_capacity = data['max_capacity']
        if len(students) > max_capacity:
            msg = 'This class is full'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)
        return data
```

Please help, I really don't know what to do. I have no idea where to place my codes. I would accept any revision or replacement of code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now your question is far more clear than previous one, try something like this to accomplish what you need:

```
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, IntegerField
from students.fields import StudentRelatedField


class ClassSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    student = StudentRelatedField(
        queryset=Student.objects.all(), many=True, required=True
    )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # We are looking here if someone wants to add students to particular class:
        if 'student' in validated_data:
            # For each of that students:
            # Also note that validated_data['student'] is a List of Objects
            for i in validated_data['student']:
                # If each of that students ARE NOT in our particular Class already:
                if i not in instance.student.all():
                    # And if our particular Class IS NOT FULL ALREADY:
                    if instance.student.count() < settings.MAX_CAPACITY:
                        # Then we will add that student to our particular Class!
                        instance.student.add(i)
                    # Otherwise we will raise an Error!
                    else:
                        raise serializers.ValidationError('This Class Is Full!')
```

Also add this to your `settings.py` file:

```
MAX_CAPACITY = 40
```

Your `students -> fields.py` file should look like:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import RelatedField

class StudentRelatedField(RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        data = {
            'id': obj.id,
            'name': obj.name
        }
        return data

    def to_internal_value(self, pk):
        return Student.objects.get(id=pk)
```